# One-to-one random database-wide text substitution

Tags: sql-server, obfuscation

Suppose I have a database with some personally identifiable information that I'd like to send to some third-party developer. It needs "real-world" data, but I need to hide people's names, addresses, etc.

Two constraints:

- Since the database is not completely normalized, there are some intentionally duplicate strings, so I need to make sure that the replacement doesn't replace those duplicates with two different values.
- The columns have different sizes, but the replacement text would have to fit in the same table. That precludes, e.g., blindly taking the first x characters of a hash.

Is there any tool or script out there that does this? If not, what would be a good way to go about this? [Global search/replace scripts](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_search_and_replace.htm) seem, at best, like a very slow and primitive building block.

Comment: might be worth stating that PID = Personally Identifiable Information.

Comment: This is not a good question for a couple reasons. First, the actual question lacks enough detail for an answer to be provided. Second, you are asking for a third party tool which is considered off topic.

Comment: @Tanner thanks. Updated